# Why can't I have more than two SSH connections to a server?

Tags: ssh, puppet, multiplexing

I am using Puppet PE 2017.3.5.0-1 on a CentOS7 AWS instance. When I SSH into this machine, to a default installation, I am getting limited to two connections only.  When I try to connect again (from a 3rd terminal) the  connection is closed automatically.

I'm not able to connect more than twice at the same time. I am using multiplexing.

I see a setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that says `MaxSessions 2`, which I highly suspect has something to do with it, but adjustments are not helping.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` there is an entry in there `MaxSessions`.  If this is set to a number `1`, this means multiplexing is disabled.  if it is set to `0`, this means that login/shell/subsystem sessions are disallowed entirely.  See here for a more descriptive answer on this here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26170/sshd-config-maxsessions-parameter.

Once you adjust this setting to 2 or more, (more than 2 in this case), or comment the line altogether, you have it correctly adjusted for more than 2 multiplexed connections now.

The problem was for me, After these settings were adjusted, I still wasnt able to connect to more than 2, even if i disconnected entirely and tried again.

I found the solution there was that you need to open the socket directory listed in `.ssh/config`, e.g. `.ssh` or `.ssh/cm_socket`, then remove the socket, because it retains this info.  Once you delete the socket, ensuring you have restarted the sshd daemon, then your new settings will take effect.